# d3js binding data using datum()

Tags: firefox, data-binding, d3.js

I've got a selection of  elements with the following data- attributes:

```
<g id="..." data-min="81" data-max="91" etc etc>
```

I'm binding the custom attributes using the datum method:

```
            var     mySelection=d3.select("#boxplots").selectAll("g.mainBoxes").datum(function(){
                return (this.dataset);
            });
```

This is working nicely - except in Firefox, where I am not getting the data appended in the DOM. Have I got the syntax of this right? Anyone aware of any workarounds or better practice?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Could you provide a complete example?

Comment: I've got a working fix now...just going to post the contrast

Comment: var mySelection=d3.select("#boxplots").selectAll("g.mainBoxes").datum(function(){
  /*I'm doing the following because
   return (this.dataset)
  doesn't appear to work on FF or IE...
  */
   var myObject = new Object();
   myObject.median=d3.select(this).attr("data-median");
   myObject.min=d3.select(this).attr("data-min");
   myObject.max=d3.select(this).attr("data-max");
   return myObject;
  });

Answer (score -2):

Firefox doesn't support attributes like `min`, `data-min` and `data-max` attributes ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)).